# Can I customize a widget icon from an app I don't develop?

Tags: app-widgets, icon-packs

I installed an icon pack (Arcticons), and some widgets don't match the design of the icon pack.
Let's take Shazam widget as an example. Can I:

- Create a custom widget icon for the existing Shazam widget?
- Create a widget with icon I want and trigger Shazam's song recognition on my own from "my widget"?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's impossible to customize the icon of an existing widget.
But depending on the app, we may be able to create a widget that launches an external application.
(Old) Source for Shazam:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791826/calling-an-extrenal-application